# Google maps not behaving the same in different machines after committing my code to SVN

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svn, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps javascript api v3. I have coded and tested the page in my machine and it works perfectly fine. But when I have committed my code to SVN and other team members downloaded my page, it's not behaving as expected. When my teammates are running it on their machines it is throwing all the markers into random locations on the map. Could anyone please let me know if they have encountered it before? Has it got anything to do with API key?

Please find my code below:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=#{MY_API_KEY}" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var i;
            function initialize() {

              geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
              var jString = JSON.parse(address);
              var contentStr;
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.3, 73.2);
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: latlng
              }
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

              for (var key in jString) {
                  contentStr = JSON.stringify(jString[key]);
                  if (jString.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                      geocodeAddress(map, key, contentStr);//end of geocode    
                  }//end of if
              }//end of for


            }//end of initialize

            function geocodeAddress(map, key, contentStr) {
                   geocoder.geocode({
                     'address': key,
                   },function(results, status){
                      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var marker = createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, contentStr);
                      }else {
                          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                        }
                   });
                }

            function createMarker(latlang, contentStr) { 
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: latlang,
                        title: contentStr
                    });
                    //alert(contentStr)
                    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentStr+" cases"
                    });
                        info.open(map, marker);
                   return marker;
            }



            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
```

Comment: What is content of `address` variable?

Comment: @AntoJurković It's a JSON array with Locations and a number associated with each location.